# Cannot add new bucket through Couchbase console deployed on OpenShift using operators

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, couchbase

we have couchbase cluster deployed on Openshift. Couchbase web console is opening but we are not able to add buckets to it. For that we have to mention buckets in Ymal file and then redeploy using openshift operator. 
Is it the general behavior or we can add buckets without re-deployment of cluster ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the intended behavior.  Much of the cluster management, like buckets and adding of nodes, is under the control of the operator.

It is possible to [disable bucket management if you have a need to](https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/current/couchbase-cluster-config.html#disablebucketmanagement), but the intent is that you'll operate through kubectl.

Comment: Thanks Matt for confirming the same... if we set disablebucketmanagement=true .. is there any downside of this change or it is just fine to manage buckets manually ?

Comment: No significant downsides.  You're effectively opting to manage that at the Couchbase Cluster level rather than at the K8S level.